# Chrome extension overrides newtab with newtab.html, then accessing cookies

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies, google-chrome-extension

On my site https://example.com, I allow users to set a cookie of their site preferences which includes letting them turn night mode on or off.

I have created a chrome extension for https://example.com that overrides Chrome's newtab with the file newtab.html. When my chrome extension opens newtab.html, I want to be able to check the preferences cookie that was set on my site https://example.com so that the new tab will also appear in night mode if the user has turned on night mode by changing the CSS.

In my manifest I have:

```
"permissions": [ "*://*/*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "https://example.com", "tabs", "cookies", "contextMenus", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "webNavigation", "activeTab", "storage", "alarms" ]
```

On my newtab.html page, I have embedded the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/newtab.js"></script>
```

newtab.js contains the following code:

```
var cookie = chrome.cookies.get({url: "example.com", name: "preferences"}); 
console.log(cookie);
```

But I get the following error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of cookies.get(object details, function callback): No matching signature.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I access exmaple.com's cookie on the newtab.html page in order to change the CSS of the newtab.html page accordingly?

Thanks in advance for your help looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chrome.cookies.get()` takes a callback as the second parameter because it may not return immediately.  The error is telling you that the function you're passing as the second parameter (`undefined` because you're *not* passing a second parameter) does not match the function signature required for the callback.  Try this:

```js
chrome.cookies.get({url: "http://example.com", name: "preferences"}, cookie => {
  console.log('got a cookie!', cookie);
});
```

Comment: Also apparently you need to pass the full url (edit by wOxxOm) :)